# Restrictions on the exponential function to make it bijective

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that with certain simple restrictions that the complex exponential function can be bijective and continuous, but while I intuitively understand the problem I'm having a tough time actually proving it.

> Let $D=D_{Polar}=\{ z=x+iy : x\in \mathbb{R}, y\in[0,2\pi)    \}$ and $\mathbb{C}^\times= \mathbb{C}-\{0 \}$. Show that $\exp|_D:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times $is bijective

I started by trying to show that its injective with the argument  $y \in[0,2\pi)$ means that  $\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$ can not be periodic, coupled with the fact that the real part of the exponential function itself is injective.  $$e^z=e^w \implies e^x \big(\cos(y)+i\sin(y) \big)= e^a \big(\cos(b)+i\sin(b) \big) \implies \frac{e^x \big( \cos(y)+i\sin(y)   \big)}{e^a \big( \cos(b)+i\sin(b) \big)}=1 \implies (e^{x-a}) \frac {\cos(y)+i\sin(y)}{\cos(b)+i\sin(b)}=1 \implies x=a, y=b. $$
For its surjectivity I know that $e^z \neq 0 $ and without $0$ in the codomain so:if $e^x=r$ $$ e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=re^{iy}=w. \implies \forall w\in \mathbb{C}- \{ 0\}  ,\exists z\in D; e^z=w.$$

I'm not sure if the arguments that I've used are good enough to call this a proof particulary one about the injectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of injectivity seems OK but it is surjectivity which lacks details. Given $w \neq 0$ take $x=\ln |w|$. Since $\frac w {|w|}$ has modulus $1$ it is of the form $e^{iy}$ for some real num ber $y$ and we can take $y \in [0,2\pi)$ (by periodicity). Now check that $e^{x+iy}=w$.